# updating adf-config.xml with WLST: Where's the mbean?

Tags: oracle-adf, mbeans, wlst

I've been trying to alter a value found in the adf-config.xml for Oracle Webcenter. I'm trying to change the default, min, and max timeouts for portlet producers. The documents say to edit the adf-config.xml, and the adf-config.xml documentation says to use WSLT to do so. I've done enough research and tinkering with WSLT that I think I understand how to do it, once I find the right MBean. I can not for the life of me find it in the MBean browser.

1) I'm specifically looking for adf-config.xml : adf-portlet-config>defaultTimeout (min&Max too)
2) A mapping document between MBeans and the various XML documents and their elements.

Any help would be much appreciated.